# 2010 Lincoln navigator stalling out

Tags: engine, shaking

So I recently moved up to a v8 engine. 2010 Lincoln navigator. As I'm driving down the road I can feel my car kind of jerk or a lose of power when my foot is on the pedal but very light and as I try to push the gas to see if everything is ok my car will instantly slow down as if it lost alot of power and it's very hard to try to turn to pull over. Itll start shaking and an odor will come out (not burning rubber) and then my car will just struggle for power I try to rev it up see if I can give some gas and itll will stall out and go to a roll. I have no idea what's going on. My first actual car problem and I'm hoping it's nothing major! Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: We would need more information to help you.  Is the check engine light on?  Does the vehicle start immediately after this, or does it require a lot of cranking, or sitting for a period of time?

Comment: Nothing comes only except for 2 times when the engine stalled out the oil light comes on. I checked oil and it's good! And sometimes it starts up like nothing happened and other times it has me sitting there for a while turning it on and off until it drives off

Comment: Next time it happens, try putting your foot to the floor on gas pedal (maxed out) and cranking for ~5 seconds, do this a couple times then try start normally.. 
If the engine has flooded (due to leaky injectors or other issues), typically this will cause the ECU to stop injecting fuel so that you can clear the flooded condition.

Honestly, there isn't enough information to diagnose really so an exact answer to this question may not be possible without more information (videos are great).

Comment: I've done that too! And sometimes itll have me sitting there trying to crank it over and over but while I'm doing this a weird smell starts to come out. As soon as my car stalls out I turn the key my car will start up then just die. I wish I could do a video but this problem happens random! Whatever info you need I can try to give you.

Comment: As I'm driving I can feel a skipping feeling while my foot is on the pedal once this happens my car will lose power in the engine slow down and start shaking and jerking struggling for power and this weird smell starts to follow and in between these my car will catch some power go really fast then come to a hard slow down my steering wheel will get really hard to turn i can put my foot on the gas but my car struggles to get up and then it stalls out and will cut off and just roll. My rpm goes up as a push the pedal but my engine fails to do the same. 2 times my oil light has come on.